# Questions about a drill-down menu app with different types of custom cells

Tags: iphone

Let me first say that by NO MEANS I am a programmer, just know the basics and just started messing with iPhone SDK. I am developing a simple app to simulate security settings for a class project, but have encountered issues even though I have found code for most of the things I want done. The main issue I have is that I don't really get how to integrate them.

In any case, the application (once running) shows 3 main options in a grouped style table view. When selecting the first option, it should take you down 1 level and be able to select an item from the list and show the checkmark for the selected item. The second option, I wanted to recreate the passcode window from the iPhone's settings (not done yet). And when the third option is selected, a list of "Apps" (I'm just throwing names there) should appear with a small icon for each and a ON/OFF switch as well. Like I said, it will be all just a simulation and all I want is for it to show properly, I am not expecting any action from the selections.

I have some code in comment, that I found and relates to what I want. I know there are variables there that don't relate to my project. I have attached my whole Project folder, here:

http://rapidshare.com/files/319884407/SecureIt.zip.html

I appreciate any help anyone can give me.

Comment: two suggestions:
1. start thinking of yourself as a programmer, since you're programming.
2. at least try to find the relevant piece of code and post it, don't make people go find your whole program, unzip it, and start looking for the right parts.

Comment: Thanks for the comment David. 1. What I really meant is that I am not a "professional" programmer nor I do it because it is my job. My programming experiences have been only out of the need to comply with course requirements. and 2. I thought about doing that at first, but since there are other elements involved, I thought anyone trying to give me a hand would want to view the other files. In any case, if no one is able to help me like this, I'll be posting another question soon to solve issues one by one. Thanks again.

Comment: I think David's point is that if you're taking a programming class, you're programming, so it's irrelevant that you're not "professional" when it comes to asking questions on SO. In other words, being a student doesn't absolve you from asking well-presented questions, which ultimately will result in better answers, which means you solve your problem, which is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You're describing a fairly standard table-driven app. I don't have the inclination to download and parse through your zipped source code, and you haven't asked a specific question, but I'll try and help anyway.

Basically, with these kinds of apps, each different screen is a separate .xib containing its own `UITableView`. Since you already have your "root" screen running, you're already familiar with this pattern. Implementing the behaviour for your first option involves detecting when a cell has been tapped, determining which cell was tapped, and then using the navigation controller to pop the next view on the stack while simultaneously clearing the selection (to follow Apple's UI guidelines).

Here's the basic pattern:

```
#pragma mark Table Delegate Methods

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([indexPath row] == 0)
    {
        FooViewController* fooViewController = [[FooViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FooView" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController fooViewController animated:YES];
        [fooViewController release];
    }
    else if ([indexPath row] == 1)
    {
        BarViewController* barViewController = [[BarViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BarView" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController barViewController animated:YES];
        [barViewController release];
    }

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES]; // Conform to Apple human-interface guidelines (Table View Programming Guide for iPhone OS)
}
```